# How can I make multiple image picker which upload and set image inside container in flutter?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

[image]

I want to make this type of image picker when I clicked on the plus sign it will open image picker when I picked images it will fit into this container.

Here is some code I've tried.

In this code, I've use flat button it will pick and image and show it under the flat button. but I want output like I mentioned in images. 5 different images uploader.

```
import 'dart:io';

import 'package:flutter/gestures.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

import 'package:image_picker/image_picker.dart';

class BusinessProfilePage extends StatefulWidget {


  @override
  _BusinessProfilePageState createState() => _BusinessProfilePageState();
}

class _BusinessProfilePageState extends State<BusinessProfilePage> {
  Future<File> profilepicture;
  bool aggreeandaccept = false;
  bool accepttudo = false;

  pickprofilepicture(ImageSource source) {
    setState(() {
      profilepicture = ImagePicker.pickImage(source: source);
    });
  }

  Widget _buildbusinessprofilepicture() {
    return new FormField(
      builder: (FormFieldState state) {
        return FlatButton.icon(
          icon: Icon(Icons.image),
          label: Text('Business Profile Picture'),
          //color: Colors.white,
          textColor: Colors.black54,
          shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(50),
          ),
          onPressed: () {
            pickprofilepicture(ImageSource.gallery);
          },
        );
      },
    );
  }

  Widget _buildprofileimage() {
    return FutureBuilder<File>(
      future: profilepicture,
      builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<File> snapshot) {
        if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.done &&
            snapshot.data != null) {
          return Image.file(
            snapshot.data,
            width: 100,
            height: 100,
          );
        } else if (snapshot.error != null) {
          return const Text(
            'Error Picking Image',
            textAlign: TextAlign.center,
          );
        } else {
          return const Text(
            'No Image Selected',
            textAlign: TextAlign.center,
          );
        }
      },
    );
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Scaffold(
      appBar: new AppBar(
        title: new Text("BusinessProfile"),
      ),
      body: Container(
        height: double.infinity,
        width: double.infinity,
        child: Stack(
          children: <Widget>[
            SingleChildScrollView(
              child: SafeArea(
                top: false,
                bottom: false,
                child: Form(
                  child: Scrollbar(
                    child: SingleChildScrollView(
                      dragStartBehavior: DragStartBehavior.down,
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 16.0),
                      child: new Container(
                        margin: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(10, 10, 10, 10),
                        child: new Column(
                          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                          children: [
                            _buildbusinessprofilepicture(),
                            _buildprofileimage(),
                          ],
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You can easily achieve this using a list, I have created a sample code for you please check this.

```
import 'package:blog_app/models/ImageUploadModel.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:image_picker/image_picker.dart';

class SingleImageUpload extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _SingleImageUploadState createState() {
    return _SingleImageUploadState();
  }
}

class _SingleImageUploadState extends State<SingleImageUpload> {
  List<Object> images = List<Object>();
  Future<File> _imageFile;
  @override
  void initState() {
    // TODO: implement initState
    super.initState();
    setState(() {
      images.add("Add Image");
      images.add("Add Image");
      images.add("Add Image");
      images.add("Add Image");
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new MaterialApp(
      home: new Scaffold(
        appBar: new AppBar(
          centerTitle: true,
          title: const Text('Plugin example app'),
        ),
        body: Column(
          children: <Widget>[
        Expanded(
          child: buildGridView(),
        ),
      ],
    ),
  ),
);
  }

  Widget buildGridView() {
    return GridView.count(
  shrinkWrap: true,
  crossAxisCount: 3,
  childAspectRatio: 1,
  children: List.generate(images.length, (index) {
    if (images[index] is ImageUploadModel) {
      ImageUploadModel uploadModel = images[index];
      return Card(
        clipBehavior: Clip.antiAlias,
        child: Stack(
          children: <Widget>[
           Image.file(
              uploadModel.imageFile,
              width: 300,
              height: 300,
            ),
            Positioned(
              right: 5,
              top: 5,
              child: InkWell(
                child: Icon(
                  Icons.remove_circle,
                  size: 20,
                  color: Colors.red,
                ),
                onTap: () {
                  setState(() {
                    images.replaceRange(index, index + 1, ['Add Image']);
                  });
                },
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      );
    } else {
      return Card(
        child: IconButton(
          icon: Icon(Icons.add),
          onPressed: () {
            _onAddImageClick(index);
          },
        ),
      );
    }
  }),
);
  }

  Future _onAddImageClick(int index) async {
setState(() {
  _imageFile = ImagePicker.pickImage(source: ImageSource.gallery);
  getFileImage(index);
});
  }

  void getFileImage(int index) async {
//    var dir = await path_provider.getTemporaryDirectory();

_imageFile.then((file) async {
  setState(() {
    ImageUploadModel imageUpload = new ImageUploadModel();
    imageUpload.isUploaded = false;
    imageUpload.uploading = false;
    imageUpload.imageFile = file;
    imageUpload.imageUrl = '';
    images.replaceRange(index, index + 1, [imageUpload]);
  });
 });
 }
 }
```

ImageUploadModel  class

```
class ImageUploadModel {
  bool isUploaded;
  bool uploading;
 File imageFile;
  String imageUrl;

  ImageUploadModel({
    this.isUploaded,
    this.uploading,
    this.imageFile,
    this.imageUrl,
  });
}
```

[image]

Comment: Hello there, I appreciate your answer but it will show an error. error is like this : uses-sdk:minSdkVersion 16 cannot be smaller than version 19 declared in library [:multi_image_picker]

Comment: open your build.gradle file in android and change  minSdkVersion 16 to  minSdkVersion 19

Comment: dear after adding this minSdkVersion the I am getting this error : D8: Program type already present: android.support.v4.app.INotificationSideChannel

Comment: you can also use ImagePicker in place of MultiImagePIcker, just remove multi image picker and change it to imagepicker

Comment: @RutvikGumasana, I've modified the code to ImagePicker please check

Comment: No dear it's not working. can you please help me to fix this problem with images picker instead of multi-image picker. I need your help. Hope you understand:)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/199222/discussion-between-kailash-chouhan-and-rutvik-gumasana).

Comment: Don't forget import 'dart:io'; otherwise you will get Type 'File' not found error.

Comment: This answer was of great help to me, and it works. Happy and a prosperous 2020 @KailashChouhan.

Comment: is there any similar library for react native?

Comment: You can use below NPM for React Native  https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-image-crop-picker/v/0.4.2

Comment: Very helpful code snippet, thanks. FYI (copied from the official readme): starting with version 0.6.7 of the image_picker plugin, the old methods that returned dart:io File objects were marked as deprecated, and a new set of methods that return PickedFile objects were introduced. More details ("Deprecation warnings in pickImage, pickVideo and LostDataResponse" section): https://pub.dev/packages/image_picker

Comment: @Kailash Chouhan Is there any way to merge all the images inside the grid box using flutter_merge, and display the result.?

Comment: null safety error can you please update the code

Answer (score 1):

You can make 4 custom buttons (with `InkWell/GestureDetector`), in their `onTap`, you can use a logic something like this for all your buttons:

```
// when button 1 is pressed, you go to image picker page, 
// select image from there and when you come back you update _image1 
Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (_) => ImagePickerPage())).then((pickedImage) {
  if (pickedImage != null) {
    setState(() {
      _image1 = pickedImage;
    });
  }
});
```

---

In your image picker page, you need to pass the image back, you'd use

```
Navigator.pop(context, pickedImage);
```

Comment: I appreciate your answer but I need this type of UI design in that design I want to pick images and this image has to fit inside these containers.

Comment: Once you have `pickedImage`, you can use it inside `Container` using `child:pickedImage`, it should't be tough.

Comment: Can you please help me to code this?. please it's my request. Because i am stuck very much in another problem can you please help me to do this. Hope you understand :). it will be very appreciated.

Comment: @RutvikGumasana I can surely help you but I am not sure which plugin you are using to pick images and also you didn't share any code, if you can share a minimal code of picking up image (the one that you are using), my job will become easy

Comment: i've attached code with the question please check it and help me to get out of this. :)

Comment: @RutvikGumasana Someone already answered it, you can use their approach.

Comment: This code has error of andoird SDK version, error is like this : uses-sdk:minSdkVersion 16 cannot be smaller than version 19 declared in library [:multi_image_picker]

Answer (score 1):

I hope you help this [multi image picker](https://pub.dev/packages/multi_image_picker) you can be used this dependency to integrate it.

Comment: I appreciate your answer but I need this type of UI design in that design I want to pick images and this image has to fit inside these containers.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [file_picker](https://pub.dev/packages/file_picker) plugin.

It supports all the plaforms and is the best for picking up files/bytes/images/videos/etc... in flutter
here is the working demo for this [github](https://github.com/JohannesMilke/firebase_upload_example)