# How to create grid layout?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

i'e case like this :

1. no image in List

[image: no image]

2. 1 image in list

[image: 1 image]

3. 2 image in List

[image: 2 image]

if image >2 in List .. this view will expand to bottom

How to create grid layout like this?

Comment: Try out this link https://stackoverflow.com/a/57864862/11404883

Comment: i get `The default 'List' constructor isn't available when null safety is enabled.` in `List<Object>` @AR

Answer (score 0):

You can use Wrap widget for the alignment and each item widgets width value you should set (screen width / 3).

For example for you;

```dart
Wrap(
              children: [
                Container(
                  width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width / 3,
                  margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 8,vertical: 4),
                  child: SelectedImageContainer(),
                ),
...add some widget and automatic align
              ],
            ),
```